# Problem with React 5 Auth Screen navigation and Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm new to react native and I'm having this problem with Auth Screen navigation and Redux Store.
So when I press "Start" it doesn't navigate to ClassesListScreen but remain in the LoginScreen. Although when I console log it print out that the "isLoggedIn" property in Store is true but it still doesn't re-render. Why is that happening? Thank you very much.

Here's my `StackNavigation.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import StudentsTabNavInit from './StudentsTabNavigation';
import LoginScreen from '../components/login/LoginScreen';
import DetailsScreen from '../components/details/DetailsScreen';
import store from '../store/store'
import AddScreen from '../components/add/AddScreen';
import ClassesListScreen from '../components/classes/ClassesListScreen';
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
function StackNavInit(){

    return (
        <StackNav.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Login"
        >
            {store.getState().isLoggedIn? (
                <> 
                <StackNav.Screen
                    name="Classes"
                    component={ClassesListScreen}
                    options={{title: "Your Classes"}}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="StudentsTabNav" 
                    component={StudentsTabNavInit} 
                    options ={{title: "Students"}}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="Details" 
                    component={DetailsScreen} 
                    options={{ title: "Details" }}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen
                    name="Add"
                    component={AddScreen}
                    options={{title: "Add Course"}}
                />
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="Login"
                    component={LoginScreen} 
                    options={{headerShown: false}}
                />
                </>
            )
        }
            
        </StackNav.Navigator>
    )
}


export default StackNavInit
```

My `LoginScreen.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Text, View, Button} from 'react-native'
import store from '../../store/store'
import {login} from '../../store/actions'
class LoginScreen extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    logIn = ()=> {
        //console.log(store.getState().isLoggedIn)
        store.dispatch(login());
        //this.props.navigation.navigate("Classes")
    };
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Welcome to Courses Managing Application</Text>
                <Text> Press Start </Text>
                <Button title="Start" onPress={this.logIn}></Button>
                <Text> {store.getState().isLoggedIn} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginScreen
```

for further information, here are things in my `store` folder (But I don't think it's related):

`actions.js`:

```
export const UPDATE_INFOR = 'UPDATE_INFOR'
export const GET_DATA = 'GET_DATA'
export const ADD_EMPLOYEE = 'ADD_EMPLOYEE'
export const DATA_REQ_SENT = 'DATA_REQ_SENT'
export const DATA_REQ_SUCCEED = 'DATA_REQ_SUCCEED'
export const DATA_REQ_FAILED = 'DATA_REQ_FAILED'
export const LOG_IN = 'LOG_IN'
export const updateInfor = (infor) => ({type: UPDATE_INFOR, payload: infor})

export const addEmployee = (infor) => ({type: ADD_EMPLOYEE, payload: infor})

export const login = () => ({type: LOG_IN})
```

`reducers.js`:

```
import defaultState from './state'
function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOG_IN':
      return {...state, isLoggedIn: true}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

`state.js`:

```
export default defaultState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
    results: 100,
    nat:'us',
    list_inc:'name,gender,dob,phone,picture,id',
}
```

`store.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
export default store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Comment: I figured out a way my self.
First wrap the App with the ` <Provider></Provider> `
then in StackNav use a Selector to connect a property `isLoggedin` to the store property with the same name, eg: `const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way my self.
First wrap the App with the `<Provider></Provider>`

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store ={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StackNavInit/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>

  );
}
```

then in StackNav use a Selector to connect a property `isLoggedin` to the store property with the same name, eg: `const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn)`
then the Navigator gonna look like:

```
function StackNavInit(){
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn)
    return (
        <StackNav.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Login"
        >
            {isLoggedIn? (
                <> 
                <StackNav.Screen
                    name="Classes"
                    component={ClassesListScreen}
                    options={{title: "Your Classes"}}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="StudentsTabNav" 
                    component={StudentsTabNavInit} 
                    options ={{title: "Students"}}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="Details" 
                    component={DetailsScreen} 
                    options={{ title: "Details" }}
                />
                <StackNav.Screen
                    name="Add"
                    component={AddScreen}
                    options={{title: "Add Course"}}
                />
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                <StackNav.Screen 
                    name="Login"
                    component={LoginScreen} 
                    options={{headerShown: false}}
                />
                </>
            )
        }
            
        </StackNav.Navigator>
    )
}
```